# UIWebView strange behavior when zooming. Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, zooming

When in my browser app I have a single webview and everything works well but double tap to zoom or pinch to zoom it seems like the screen zooms to the location, flies of the screen then redraws it's self. It happens in a flash but it's very distracting. In Safari Mobile the zoom is nice and smooth. How is this being achieved?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so in my view controller I have a scrollview that needs to hide on an action so in my view controller.h file I had this code in various areas to initiate the animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
```

And in webview I didn't have any reference to UIView Animation at all. I added:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
```

That went in didbegin & didfinish just to be safe and it seems to have fixed the problem.